# Determining whether a mode was enabled

Tags: variables, minor-mode

Is it possible to determine whether `global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode` or `display-fill-column-indicator-mode` was enabled?

I am running Emacs 27.2.

Comment: I'm guessing this question is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All minor modes have an associated variable that's the same name as the function to toggle the mode. When a mode is local and has a global variant, the global variant has its own variable.

So, for example, to check whether Display-Fill-Column-Indicator mode is enabled in the current buffer, check the value of the variable `display-fill-column-indicator-mode`. You don't need to worry whether it was turned on via the local or global function: `display-fill-column-indicator-mode` reflects whether the mode is active in the buffer regardless of how it was activated.

Comment: Right.  But when `global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode` was enabled by the user and I want to disable on all buffers, then I also can do `(if global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode`?

Comment: @Randy The mode can be disabled in some buffers even if it's enabled globally, and can be enabled in some buffers even if it's disabled globally. `(global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode 0)` disables the mode in all buffers. You can check the variable `global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode` to see if the global mode is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Evaluate `(memq 'display-fill-column-indicator-mode local-minor-modes)`.

Comment: Not sure about this one.  Does `local-minor-modes` actually exist?

Comment: Did you do `C-h v local-minor-modes`?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it not work? If not, what was the problem? Just adding a comment without actually testing anything is useless: either test it and say what exactly went wrong or accept the answer. FWIW, I tested it and it seems to work as advertised.

Comment: Not in Emacs 27.2

Comment: That would be the thing to say in your first comment - version differences are also why it is important to always specify the version of your emacs (plus any other relevant packages) *in your question*. In this instance, the variable was called `minor-modes` and it was renamed to `local-minor-modes` at some point, but I'm not sure in which release: try the earlier name `minor-modes` instead.

Comment: Have not found it listed upon doing `C-h v`.

Comment: I see what you mean: I think it's only available (under either name) in Emacs 29 (at least I can't find it in emacs 28.2).